# How to subtract two columns of lists from each other in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, text

I have data in a tab-separated value text file that look like this:

```
FileName    Onsets          Offsets
FileName1   [9, 270, 763]   [188, 727, 1252]
FileName2   [52, 634, 1166, 1775, 2104] [472, 1034, 1575, 1970, 2457]
FileName3   [180, 560, 1332, 1532]  [356, 1286, 1488, 2018]
```

These are data from audio files. Each row contains a series of onset and offset times for each of the sounds I'm researching.

In the first row of data, 9 is the onset time of the first sound, and 188 is the offset time of the first sound. That means it lasted for 179 ms.

I need the durations for each sound, and the gaps of silence between each sound.

Currently I read the data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('/path/file.txt', delimiter='\t')
    
FileName = data[["FileName"]].to_numpy()  
Onsets = data[["Onsets"]].to_numpy()  
Offsets = data[["Offsets"]].to_numpy()
```

That gives me three numpy arrays. For the onsets and offsets, each row is actually an array of the numbers in the original data file.

What code can I use to extract those numbers so that I can then subtract the onset times from the offset times to determine the durations?

Comment: Any quotes in the file?  What about the `Onsets` and `Offsets` arrays?  Shape, dtype?  I suspect you have loaded those things that look like lists as strings.  Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first issue is, you have columns of strings that must be converted to lists, using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- In order to perform array subtracting, convert the values in `'Onsets'` and `'Offsets'` to [`numpy.arrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)
- To calculate the gaps of silence:

  - The first gap of silence between `[9, 270, 763]` and `[188, 727, 1252]` begins at `188` and end at `270`.
  - To perform the array calculation, subtract the first two elements of `Offsets` from the last two elements of `Onsets`

    - `270 - 188` and `763 - 727`
    - `x[0][1:]` is all but the first element of `Onsets`
    - `x[1][:-1]` is all but the last element of `Offsets`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

# load data and use literal_eval to converts strings to lists
data = pd.read_csv('/path/file.txt', delimiter='\t', converters={'Onsets': literal_eval, 'Offsets': literal_eval})

# convert rows of lists to numpy arrays
data[['Onsets', 'Offsets']] = data[['Onsets', 'Offsets']].applymap(np.array)

# subtract the values in the arrays
data['duration'] = data.Offsets.sub(data.Onsets)  # data.Offsets - data.Onsets can also be used

# calculate the gaps of silence
data['gaps'] = data[['Onsets', 'Offsets']].apply(lambda x: x[0][1:] - x[1][:-1], axis=1)

# display(data)
    FileName                       Onsets                        Offsets                   duration                  gaps
0  FileName1                [9, 270, 763]               [188, 727, 1252]            [179, 457, 489]              [82, 36]
1  FileName2  [52, 634, 1166, 1775, 2104]  [472, 1034, 1575, 1970, 2457]  [420, 400, 409, 195, 353]  [162, 132, 200, 134]
2  FileName3       [180, 560, 1332, 1532]        [356, 1286, 1488, 2018]       [176, 726, 156, 486]         [204, 46, 44]
```

Comment: Thank you! This a is very clear answer and helps me understand what I was doing wrong.